# Safari on ios won't select better quality HLS video

Tags: ios, video, safari, http-live-streaming

Thanks for your attention.

I've used `ffmpeg` to produce several videos in different resolutions,and use the `Apple HTTP Live Streaming Tools` to make segments for each video.However, when I try to play the main m3u8 playlist. My iPhone 12Pro just won't select video of better quality even when the network bandwidth is quite sufficient.

My main playlist is

```
#EXTM3U

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=3142400,BANDWIDTH=4399772,VIDEO-RANGE=SDR,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.64001f",RESOLUTION=1112x556,FRAME-RATE=29.970,CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
480/prog_index.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=12466974,BANDWIDTH=15558489,VIDEO-RANGE=SDR,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.640032",RESOLUTION=2368x1184,FRAME-RATE=29.970,CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
SD/prog_index.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:AVERAGE-BANDWIDTH=22605736,BANDWIDTH=26980017,VIDEO-RANGE=SDR,CODECS="mp4a.40.2,avc1.640032",RESOLUTION=3328x1664,FRAME-RATE=29.970,CLOSED-CAPTIONS=NONE
HD/prog_index.m3u8
```

I host the m3u8 file by using vscode `Live Server` and visit this html with ios device.

```html
<video  controls>
    <source src="main.m3u8">
</video>
```

When Safari played this HTML, at first, I noticed that only `480P` video would be played. And if I turned it into fullscreen `SD` quality video would then be selected.However, the 'HD' quality would just never be an option of Safari even the network bandwidth is good enough.I tried to remove all the other playlist except `HD` then Safari played HD by default as if Safari had no other choice but to choose HD.

My question is how can I let Safari select better quality of hls video ? I've searched over the internet and it seems there is no other option to set on  HTML element. It's quite a big problem for me since MSE is not supported on iOS of iPhone. I just can't find other way to solve this problem.

Thanks for all your attention. I'm looking forward to your precious advices.

Comment: I finally fix this issue. The  Safari on iOS restricts the max resolution of video source. So what I have done is mainly modify the resolution to smaller scale of the master m3u8 playlist of high resolution videos. Then Safari finally is willing to select higher resolution. That really sucks. It requires more documentation.

Comment: What scales worked well for you?

Comment: yeah, what is the detail to solve this issue? iOS looks so weird